# Add or remove loss function based on wether sample is labeled or not in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I want to implement PI Model architecture proposed in this paper "TEMPORAL ENSEMBLING FOR SEMI-SUPERVISED
LEARNING".
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjKiqyMmOfZAhXGz4MKHcFJCxEQFgguMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fabs%2F1610.02242&usg=AOvVaw3VuNNeChU0O7WYXZQsfxOh.

The authors provided the code in theano but theano is no longer supported so I am writing the algorithm in tensorflow. 
The paper is about semi-supervised model where a  batch of training data contains both labeled and unlabeled samples. The algorithm has two branches - one for labeled and the other for unlabeled samples. One sample serves as the input to the two branches, however in ech branch the input undergoes random augmentation. In the labeled branch the cross entropy loss is used between the label and the output of a CNN while for the unlabeled branch, the mean square loss between the outputs of a CNN for the two random augmented versions of the same input is used.

I am using cifar10 dataset and I have randomly changed the lables of some samples to 10 to represent the unlabled samples. For either labeled or unlabled sample, the mean square will always be part of the training loss, however if the sample is unlabeled(i.e, the label == 10) then cross entropy should be zero.

I have come up with the following snippet in my code

```
sentinel = tf.Variable(-1, name='sentinel')

if tf.argmax(y_, axis=1)[0] != tf.constant(10):

    sentinel = sentinel
else:
    sentinel = 1

cross_entropy = tf.cond(tf.greater(sentinel, tf.constant(0)), lambda: tf.constant(0.0), lambda: tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=train_prediction)), name ='cross_entropy')

train_loss = cross_entropy

mean_sq_loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(train_prediction, train_prediction_b)
train_loss += unsup_weight * mean_sq_loss
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(config.adam_epsilon).minimize(train_loss)
```

but the condition

```
if tf.argmax(y_, axis=1)[0] != tf.constant(10):
```

does not evaluate to true even when 
tf.argmax(y_, axis=1)[0] equals 10.

I used sentinel to track if the sample is labeled or not but when I checked the output for a batch size of 1, sentinel does not change even when the sample is unlabeled. I will appreciate any contribution.
Thanks

Comment: The reason your condition does not work is because you are trying to compare tensors using Python logical operations. Instead of making up a new class, just set the `weights` argument in [tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/softmax_cross_entropy) to `0.0` for the samples you want to ignore.

Comment: @mikkola i am using the comparison to find out if the sample is labeled or not as the model does not have this knowledge. The samples may come as labeled or unlabeled. So I need a way to make the comparison work. Thank you